# Is overflow happening here?

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

I couldn't get why this program is giving this output. Is overflow happening here ?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     __int64 fileAgeInFileTime ;
     fileAgeInFileTime = 24  *60 * 60 ;

     cout << fileAgeInFileTime << endl;

     fileAgeInFileTime *= 10000000;

     __int64 fileAgeInFileTime2 = 24  *60 * 60  * 10000000 ;

     cout << fileAgeInFileTime << "  " <<fileAgeInFileTime2;

    return 0;
}
```

O/P :

86400

864000000000  711573504

I couldnt understand why fileAgeInFileTime and fileAgeInFileTime2 have different values ?

The real requirement is to get the 100 nano second resolution of file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's an overflow. You multiply four `int` constants and assign them to `__int64`.

`__int64` can be saved inside `long long` (`long long` should have at least 64 bits since C++11). You need to mark your constants as `long long` like this:

```
__int64 fileAgeInFileTime2 = 24LL * 60LL * 60LL * 10000000LL;
```

Or mark the first of those constants as `LL`, the others are implicitly converted:

```
__int64 fileAgeInFileTime2 = 24LL * 60 * 60 * 10000000;
```

Some kind of cast also works (other variables are also implicitly converted):

```
__int64 fileAgeInFileTime2 = static_cast<__int64>(24) * 60 * 60 * 10000000;
```

The last line should also explain why

```
__int64 fileAgeInFileTime2 = 10000000;
fileAgeInFileTime2 *= 24 * 60 * 60;
```

works. This multiplies four `int`s, converts the result to `int64` and multiplies it by `fileAgeInFileTime2`. The total result is then assign to `fileAgeInFileTime2`.

Comment: Or use `auto` in a single assignment.

Comment: You should mark the first constant as LL, not only the last. Marking only the last works here by chance, because the first are so small.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have overflow here. When you multiply `int` by `int`, the result is also int, so you have overflow while calculating `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000000`. After this the incorrect result is stored in `__int64` variable.

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) type conversions for arithmetic operators are explained